# Silverlight and unsafe code

Tags: silverlight, unsafe

I know there is no direct way to have unsafe code in silverlight C# code but nothing really stops us from having unsafe code in a WCF service, and then referencing this service from Silverlight, yes? Probably not the ideal thing to do but has anyone ever needed to do such a thing? I'm thinking I may need this but not sure of any other way to get around it, especially since the code I need to acces is writtenin C++.

THanks much

Comment: Not exactly a question, but yes, I face the same problem.  I want to render a heatmap on the client and compositing image data is orders of magnitude faster using *ptr arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

@David, if this is still an issue for you, Silverlight 5 looks promising with respect to unsafe code. Please have a look at this blog post on my attempts to enable unsafe code support in Silverlight 5 RC: http://cureos.blogspot.com/2011/09/unsafe-support-in-silverlight-5.html

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there's nothing stopping you from using unsafe code on the server-side.